# Trace and Determinant of Field Extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, determinant, extension-field, trace

In algebra, we had a look at the trace and the determinant of a field extension. I am familiar with those concepts in linear algebra and I have seen that finite extensions can be viewed as a finite vectorspace.

I am seeking for some explanations why those concepts are helpful and what they are really used for. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Trace and norm are very important for algebraic number theory. See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/825397/trace-norm-of-field-extension-vs-trace-determinant-of-linear-operators).

Comment: If you have a field extension L/K where you know a lot about K and not much about L, then a first natural idea would be to take the trace (if + is concerned) or the norm (if x is concerned) to go down and get some information. Of course, you lose sight of the elements who are in the respective kernels, but there are general theorems which describe them. For instance , if L/K is Galois cyclic, the so called Hilbert theorems 90 (fot + and x resp.) do the job. More generally, if L/K is Galois with group G, the cohomology groups H^1( G, L) and H^1(G, L*) do the same.

Comment: Addendum : In number theory, the norm plays a fundamental role in the description of abelian extensions of a given number field K (curiously, the trace does not). If L/K is an abelian extension of local fields, local class field theory essentially shows that Gal(L/K) is canonically isomorphic to K*/Norm (L*). For number fields, global class field theory shows the same, provided the multiplicative groups are replaced by the "idèle class groups" of the fields .